# Kivy MD : Displaying multiple lists in a single row

Tags: python, list, scrollview, grid-layout, kivymd

I'm new to developing in kivy. I've been learning the basics and checking the documentation. My problem is that I wanna display multiple lists - let's say 2 lists - in a single row.

Here is my code:

```
...

# Python file
class NoteBox(OneLineListItem):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint_x = None
        self.size_hint_y = None
        self.size = (150, 150)
        self.color = (0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1)
...

# Kivy file
#:kivy 2.1.0
Screen: 
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        MDToolbar:
            title: 'hello world'
            left_action_items: [['menu']]
            right_action_items: [['dots-vertical']]
            elevation: 12
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            spacing: 20
            padding: 10
            height: self.minimum_height
            ScrollView:
                MDList:
                    NoteBox:
                        text: 'a'
                    NoteBox:
                        text: 'b'
                    NoteBox:
                        text: 'c'
                    NoteBox:
                        text: 'd'
                    NoteBox:
                        text: 'e'
                    NoteBox:
                        text: 'f'
                    NoteBox:
                        text: 'g'
```

Running this code results in displaying a `ScrollView` of lists arranged vertically, one list per row.

Comment: `MDList` itself is derived from `GridLayout`. So setting its `cols` equal to 2 should work.

Comment: I'm glad that helped. That's all.

Comment: But the question has to be answered, and that's you who found the answer.